# SELECT dates where IN(NULL,>=SYSDATE)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is that possible?  Can one

```
SELECT * FROM DATES_TBL WHERE DATES_TBL.DATES IN(NULL, >=SYSDATE)
```

?  Maybe I am formatting it incorrectly, or missing a tick?

What I would like to `select` are values from the date field that are `NULL` or greater than today's date (`>=SYSDATE`).  Any help would be appreciated.

SQL 10g

Comment: Where is your FROM clause?

Comment: I was just generalizing and forgot it.  I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATES_TBL
WHERE DATES IS NULL OR DATES >= SYSDATE
```

Comment: Every time I try to use an OR clause it causes a lot of run time, sometimes over 10 minutes.  That is why I wanted to use the IN clause if I could.  It seems to work better on these large queries (I am selecting upwards of 45 different columns with pivots, etc.)

Comment: I ended up using this logic, but closed the `OR` as such:

`SELECT * 
FROM DATES_TBL
WHERE (DATES IS NULL OR DATES >= SYSDATE)`

This cut down the run time and gathered my results.  Thank you for the suggestion that prompted my answer.

Comment: Oh my goodness.... adding the parentheses has nothing to do with the performance of your query...

Answer (score 1):

The NULL value is a special value so you must write your statement like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DATES_TBL
WHERE  DATES IS NULL
OR     DATES >= SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a valid syntax: `IN` queries require specific items; also, because in SQL null never equals anything, including other nulls, it does not make sense to put nulls into an `IN` list.

What you need instead is an `OR`:

```
SELECT * WHERE (DATES_TBL.DATES IS NULL) OR (DATES_TBL.DATES>=SYSDATE)
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                |                             |
--                |                             +- This is how you compare for >=
--                +------------- This is how you check for NULL
```

> Every time I try to use an OR clause it causes a lot of run time

In cases when `OR` is introduced to combine non-overlapping results (which is true in this case, because a column is either `null` or is greater than `SYSDATE`, but not both) you can use `UNION ALL` to potentially speed up the search:

```
SELECT * WHERE DATES_TBL.DATES IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * WHERE DATES_TBL.DATES >= SYSDATE
```

You need to make sure that `DATES_TBL.DATES` column is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Oracle, try this:

SELECT * FROM DATES_TBL WHERE (DATES_TBL.DATES is null or DATES_TBL.DATES >= sysdate)

The parenthesis make it work.